# Код C#, смена Спрайта кнопки

Tags: c#

у меня есть код, который позволяет купить скин, и мне осталось сделать только способ одевать/снимать его:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Globalization;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class Skins : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CameraManager CameraManager;
    public GameObject buttonBuy;
    public GameObject changeSkin;
    public GameObject returnSkin;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private int skin1Money = 1000000;
    private bool dressed = false;
    private string dressedT;
    private string buy = "true";
    void Start()
    {
        buy = PlayerPrefs.GetString("buy", buy);
        buttonBuy.SetActive(bool.Parse(buy));
        dressedT = PlayerPrefs.GetString("dressed", dressedT);
        dressed = bool.Parse(dressedT);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    public void Skin1()
    {
        if (CameraManager.score >= skin1Money && dressed == false && buy == "true")
        {
            buy = "false";
            dressed = true;
            CameraManager.score -= skin1Money;
            buttonBuy.SetActive(bool.Parse(buy));
            changeSkin.SetActive(true);
            dressedT = dressed.ToString();
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("buy", buy);
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("dressed", dressedT);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", CameraManager.score);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
        }
    }
    private void Awake()
    {
        CameraManager = GetComponent<CameraManager>();
    }
}
```

Также добавлю, что кнопка changeSkin меняет скин, а отдельная кнопка returnSkin возвращает изначальный.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.